# Can a weak acid ever fully dissociate?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

From what I understand, the pH of the solution the weak acid is added to determines the extent that the weak acid will dissociate. But would there be a pH which would allow the weak acid to fully dissociate?

Comment: In mathematical sense (no molecule left)? Or in scientific sense (too little left in given context to be detected or to matter) ? // Note that even strong acids do not fully dissociate in the former sense, as their Ka is very high, but not infinite.

Comment: A weak acid is in equilibrium as $\ce{HA + H2O \rightleftharpoons  A^- + H3O^+}$ so the position of equilibrium can be altered by adding or reducing acid or base concentrations just as for any equilibrium. If you want close to 100% dissociation, probably unlikely but 80% may be possible depending on equilibrium constant and realistic concentrations. What is possible depends on the weak acid used and you will have to calculate this.

Comment: At what temperature? At sufficiently high temperature, *everything* can be considered dissociated.

Comment: Not even "strong"  acid dissociate all that completely https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/143459/do-strong-acids-actually-dissociate-completely

Comment: If the acid is not _too_ weak, we can come close to full dissociation by making it very dilute. See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/118826/strength-of-bases-and-acids/145644#145644.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, no acid is fully ionized in water solutions. Even strong acid solution has traces of a not dissociated forms, as their acidity constants are very high, but not infinite.

For all practical purposes, we consider the acid as fully dissociated if the not dissociated form is negligible for given purpose or context.

All strong acids can be considered fully dissociated in not too concentrated water solutions. It is obvious the solution with molar ratio $\ce{2 H2SO4}$ : $\ce{1 H2O}$ cannot be fully dissociated, as a part of the acids has no water available to be protonated.

For weak acids, if there is required e.g. 99.9% (99.99%) of dissociated form, the requirement is fullfilled at $\mathrm{pH} \ge \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + 3(4)$

Answer (score 0):

Yes there would, simply add strong base in sufficient quantity.  The pH curve will show the weak acid buffering until it is fully depleted, then a sharp rise in pH.

This would be under the assumption that the weak acid and its deprotonated form are both fully soluble.  This is essentially how soap is made from fatty acids.

> pH = pKa + log (salt/acid)

One can see as the strong base depletes the weak acid, **pH becomes the negative log of the (proton) dissociation constant of either the solvent or the protonated form of the strong base!**

The former weak acid simply becomes a salt in that solution.

Comment: Even if you add that much base it's still not completely deprotonated. And if you add enough to make it so, it's not an acid but a salt in a solution of the base.

Comment: @Mithoron "even when you add that much base"?.  It's not quantity, it's strength.  The concentration of acid form is essentially zero, **especially considering solvent effects**, once sufficient strong base is added.

Comment: In water an acidic solution contains a [H3O+] > sqrt Kw so any weak acid no matter how dilute will not be 100% ionized. The product of hydronium ion and conjugate base will always be too high. To make a weak acid strong a more basic solvent is necessary. [Please ignore for now the small amounts remaining because Keq is not infinity.]

Comment: @jimchmst One can look at it this way, adding strong base to the solvent **changes the pKa of the acid**, reducing its concentration to essentially zero.

Comment: Did I not say a more basic solvent?